# chef knife bootstrap admin users

Tags: chef-infra, knife, databags

For reasons I won't go into I have some chef recipes that need to edit the contents of a data bag. Thus, I believe, the node user profile needs to be "admin: true". So when I bootstrap a node  (knife bootstrap) the first pass fails with a http 403 error (unable to edit contents of the data bag) and I have to go in and manually set that user to admin.

Is there a way to do that on by default with the knife bootstrap command? I suppose I could create the users beforehand, but I would rather just let chef to all the bootstrapping for me.

Note: I'm using chef 10 and open source chef server

Answer (score 2):

The knife bootstrap operation passes the chef validation key to new node so that it can create a new "client" registration. This is the credential used by chef-client.

There is a subtle difference between "users" and "clients" in Chef. The former is generally what is used to with knife. I don't think it's possible to create admin clients and to be honest I'm not aware of a use case that requires it. Could be considered a risk as clients should not be allowed to make changes that might impact other nodes.

Please read 'Create and Edit' section at https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html. Which says it is not advisable to do so (for editing data bags with nodes). From security perspective its highly **not recommended**

To achieve your desired result, perhaps just use the "knife" command configured to use an admin user. chef-client and knife use different configuration files.